# Joining two tables (Vlookup)

Tags: sql-server

I want to join two tables from different data bases on SQL server. Please assist.
First table:

```
[Ln_Audit].[dbo].[ttccom112101_AUD] a

Name    Color    Shoe size
Jason   Red       9
Amanda  Blue      8
Sandy   Brown     8
Chris   Orange    7
```

Second table:

```
[erplndb].[dbo].[ttccom100101] b

Name    Age
Sandy   12
Amanda  14
Chris   16
Jason   11

Desired table
Name     Shoe_Size Age  Color
Sandy    8         12   Brown
Amanda   8         14   Blue
Chris    7         16   Orange
Jason    9         11   Red
```

May you please assist me, I am working on SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

You get this by using a simple [inner join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx) on the `name` column:

```
select a.name, a.shoe_size, b.age, a.color 
from [Ln_Audit].[dbo].[ttccom112101_AUD] a 
                      join [erplndb].[dbo].[ttccom100101] b
                      on a.name = b.name
```

Comment: Thank you. I for got to mention that 'name' is written as 'Title' in the second table. Can this only be done if the column headings are identical ?

Comment: Yes, just change the condition like this: `on a.name = b.title`, but you need to be sure that those are the columns you need to match.